# TF_SessionRun_wrapper: expected all values in input dict to be ndarray

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't think I've ever had this error before and I don't really understand what it is saying. Even in a simple test case (shown below), I run into this error.

This is specifically on one machine, but not on other computers. So, I think it must be a configuration/setup problem? I am not quite sure how to progress...

If there are any hints/If anyone has run into this error before, it would be great to know especially considering there is no information about it online.

I am using Tensorflow version `1.13.0-dev20190208` (GPU nightly build) with CUDA 10.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def multiply(input):
    return (input * 3)

input_pl = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(3,), name='input_pl')
out = multiply(input_pl)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    np_input  = np.array([1, 0, 0])
    out_np = sess.run([out], {input_pl: np_input}) # Error here

    print(out_np)
```

Comment: I fixed the issue through reinstalling and making sure environment was correct.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm sure that it's linked to the environment but I don't really know which package is causing the problem. Could you give me information about the environment you're using and where was the problem exactly?

Comment: @MounaBenChamekh Are you using the nightly build?

Comment: no, but the problem for me was that another package installed a dependency but the version was not the good one. I specified the required version and it's solved. Thank you!